# Entity Framework C# change value in table by id

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have Estate and Contract tables. Estate table has Boolean property (Available). When clients are confirms their contract Available property in Estate table changing its value to false. Estate selects from combobox by EstateID. Problem is that I don’t know how to get access to Available property by ID selected in EstateCombobox.

```
contract.ContractDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ContractDateTextBox.Text);
            contract.OperationType = OperationTypeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            contract.Description = DescriptionTextBox.Text;
            contract.EstateID = Convert.ToInt32(EstateComboBox.SelectedValue);
            contract.ClientID = Convert.ToInt32(ClientComboBox.SelectedValue);
            contract.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(EmployeeComboBox.SelectedValue);
            contract.NewOwnerID = Convert.ToInt32(NewClientOwnerComboBox.SelectedValue)



EstateComboBox.DataSource = AgencyContext.Estate.ToList();
        EstateComboBox.DisplayMember = "EstateName";
        EstateComboBox.ValueMember = "EstateID";
        EstateComboBox.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly:

```
int eid = Convert.ToInt32(EstateComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
var myEstate = AgencyContext.Estate.Single(e => e.EstateID == eid);

myEstate.Available = false; //new value

dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Something wrong  in part Select(e => e.EstateID == EstateComboBox.SelectedValue) compiler shows warning:"Cannot apply operator '==' to operand type 'int' and 'object'"

Comment: This time compiler marked 'e' as error: a parameter name ‘e’ cannot be declared in this scope because it would get different meaning to ‘e’ which already is used in a parent or current scope to denote something else

Comment: change `e` to something else, it conflict with another variable. Make it `ee`

Comment: Can you explain me what did we get by this expression? If I understand correctly we get EstateID but how I can change Available property to false now?

Comment: @qr11 can you see my new code? you need to use `SaveChanges` method of your dbcontext class

Comment: Doesnt compile. myEstate.Available: Cannot resolve symbol 'Available'

Comment: @qr11 mine was a type (Avaiable), you have `Available` property right? can you try again?

Comment: value doesnt changed it still true

Comment: @qr11 I have no idea, I think you should share your current code along with dbcontext.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add  dbContext.Estate.Add(estate). It works. thank you for your help.